# Joining 3 MySQL tables, error code 1242 returns more than 1 row

Tags: php, mysql, join, html-table

I have the following tables:

Golfers:

```
| vID | vGolfer |
|-----|---------|
| 1   | Johnson |
| 2   | Thomas  |
| 3   | Rahm    |
| 4   | Spieth  |
| 5   | Rose    |
```

Roster:

```
| key | vPlayer | vID |
|-----|---------|-----|
| 1   | Player1 | 1   |
| 2   | Player1 | 2   |
| 3   | Player1 | 3   |
| 4   | Player1 | 4   |
| 5   | Player1 | 5   |
```

Where Roster.vID=Golfers.vID and each player is able to select 5 golfers to be a part of their "roster".

Scores:

```
| key | vID | vRound | vScore |
|-----|-----|--------|--------|
| 1   | 1   | Rd1    | 71     |
| 2   | 1   | Rd2    | 70     |
| 3   | 1   | Rd3    | 71     |
| 4   | 1   | Rd4    | 69     |
```

where Scores.vID=Golfers.vID.

My goal is to display each "Roster" in a table in a webpage with the following output:

```
| Player1 | Rd1 | Rd2 | Rd3 | Rd4 |
|---------|-----|-----|-----|-----|
| Johnson | 71  | 68  | 72  | 69  |
| Spieth  | 70  | 70  | 68  | 71  |
| Thomas  | 72  | 71  | 71  | 70  |
| Rahm    | 69  | 68  | 71  | 70  |
```

I've attempted to use the following query:

```
SELECT
g.vName,  
(select vPlayer from vroster where vID = g.vID) as Player,
(select vScore from vscorecard where vID = g.vID and vRound='Rd1') as Round1
(select vScore from vscorecard where vID = g.vID and vRound='Rd2') as Round2
(select vScore from vscorecard where vID = g.vID and vRound='Rd3') as Round3
(select vScore from vscorecard where vID = g.vID and vRound='Rd4') as Round4
FROM  vgolfers g
```

However I'm getting an Error Code 1242. Subquery returns more than 1 row. I understand I'm trying to get multiple rows where vPlayer = "Player1" and for each subsequent player, but how do I get around this?

Comment: Your upvoting/acceptance record's not the best, is it?

Comment: Also I cannot see how you derive that result set from that data set

Comment: @Strawberry, I can own that my post is rough and can accept valid criticism. What is missing in your life that you post a response to this without providing any positive feedback? If it's beyond help, don't bother. I doubt you are perfect with everything you try the first time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of things wrong with your example data:

1. Your use of `key` as a column name. I don't even know how you got your table setup like that, so I used `keyx` because this is just an example. Look up the reserved word [key](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table.html) here.
2. You're missing commas after each alias (`Round1`,`Round2`,`Round3`).
3. The example table names are not what you are using in your sample query (`Golfers` vs `vgolfers`; `Scores` vs `vscorecard`, etc..)
4. The column `g.vName` doesn't exist, but `g.vGolfer` does.

Anyway...

You didn't provide scores for golfer named Rose, so I just entered `0` for their score.

The following query will display what it appears you wanted:

```
SELECT
g.vGolfer,  
(select vPlayer from Roster where vID = g.vID) as Player,
(select vScore from Scores where vID = g.vID and vRound='Rd1') as Round1,
(select vScore from Scores where vID = g.vID and vRound='Rd2') as Round2,
(select vScore from Scores where vID = g.vID and vRound='Rd3') as Round3,
(select vScore from Scores where vID = g.vID and vRound='Rd4') as Round4
FROM  Golfers g
```

[image]

Please take a look at this [[DEMO]](http://rextester.com/AFDLAJ50060)

---

**EDIT**: If you have additional Players:

```
SELECT
g.vGolfer,  
r.vPlayer as Player,
MAX(CASE WHEN s.vround = 'Rd1' THEN s.vScore ELSE 0 END) AS Rd1,
MAX(CASE WHEN s.vround = 'Rd2' THEN s.vScore ELSE 0 END) AS Rd2,
MAX(CASE WHEN s.vround = 'Rd3' THEN s.vScore ELSE 0 END) AS Rd3, 
MAX(CASE WHEN s.vround = 'Rd4' THEN s.vScore ELSE 0 END) AS Rd4 
FROM  Golfers g 
INNER JOIN Roster r ON g.vID = r.vID
INNER JOIN Scores s ON g.vID = s.vID AND r.keyx = s.keyx
GROUP BY g.vGolfer, r.vPlayer
ORDER BY r.vPlayer, g.vGolfer
```

[image]

[[UPDATED DEMO]](http://rextester.com/VHV14877)

Comment: I really appreciate the help and sorry for the very horrible original post. That worked perfectly.

Comment: @Speight thank you, and no sweat. Your question visually looked like it was good to go but then when I started trying to link the tables together in my head and then referenced your attempt, I was way thrown off. Some people on here can solve a problem like this completely in their head without testing, and they might just say the hell with it if the test data is goofy. I on the other hand can’t solve many of them without testing my work, so oh well. Some of my first questions were terrifying. (Now I find it hard to ask a question that I can’t find an answer to on this site) anyway, cheers.

Comment: That works perfect when there is only a single 'Player', if I have multiple 'Player's, I receive Error Code 1242. Subquery returns more than 1 row.

Comment: @Speight - I don't have any more time this evening, please check out my edit and DEMO. I've added more data and changed up the query a little bit, using [MAX](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-maximum-column.html) and [JOIN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
g.vgolfer as player1,
max( case when s.vround = 'Rd1' then s.vscore else 0 end  ) as Rd1,
max( case when s.vround = 'Rd2' then s.vscore else 0 end  ) as Rd2,
max( case when s.vround = 'Rd3' then s.vscore else 0 end  ) as Rd3, 
max( case when s.vround = 'Rd4' then s.vscore else 0 end  ) as Rd4 
from scores s
inner join roster r
on s.vid = r.vid
inner join golfers g
on r.vid = g.vid 
where r.vplayer = 'player1'
group by g.vgolfer
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cce262/5) - copied the non-zero test data from Brien's `scores` table to verify the test results.

Answer (score 0):

These code as follows may provide what you want.

```
SELECT vGolfer Player1, 
(SELECT vScore From Scores WHERE Golfers.vID = vID AND vRound = 'Rd1') Rd1,
(SELECT vScore From Scores WHERE Golfers.vID = vID AND vRound = 'Rd2') Rd2,
(SELECT vScore From Scores WHERE Golfers.vID = vID AND vRound = 'Rd3') Rd3,
(SELECT vScore From Scores WHERE Golfers.vID = vID AND vRound = 'Rd4') Rd4
FROM Golfers, Roster
WHERE Golfers.vID = Roster.vID and Roster.vPlayer = 'Player1'
```

**Result**

```
Player1 Rd1 Rd2 Rd3 Rd4
Johnson 71  70  71  69
Thomas  72  71  71  70
Rahm    69  68  71  70
Spieth  70  70  68  71
Rose    (null)  (null)  (null)  (null)
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/eb2dde/23)